# Creating a For All function in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

This might be hard to explain, but I am trying to create implement a formula that compares a bunch of values of "TRUE" or "FALSE" and then displays an output a corresponding cell that states if at least one "FALSE" exist, then group is false.

In theory it would look like:

```
1   TRUE    FALSE
1   TRUE    FALSE
1   FALSE   FALSE
1   FALSE   FALSE
1   FALSE   FALSE
2   TRUE    TRUE
2   TRUE    TRUE
2   TRUE    TRUE
2   TRUE    TRUE
2   TRUE    TRUE
3   TRUE    FALSE
3   TRUE    FALSE
3   FALSE   FALSE
```

So in Column C has the formula that in theory would group it. Note there are 3000 cells with about roughly 150 groups. Hence brute force isn't an ideal option.

Answer (score 1):

In C1:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A1,B:B,FALSE)=0
```

Then copy down.

[image]